# How to merge column names and drop columns in pandas after reading to html

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to clean up a pandas dataframe taken from a html table. I am using `dfs = pd.read_html(table_html)` to generate the frame. After reading the html into pandas it looks like so:

```
            Time                               ABC|XX3                   ABC|XX3            ABC|XX3 
            Time Day-ahead Total Load Forecast [A.L.1] Actual Total Load [A.L.1] Unnamed: 3_level_1
            Time                                  [MW]                      [MW] Unnamed: 3_level_2
0  00:00 - 01:00                                 10169                         -
1  01:00 - 02:00                                 10092                         -
2  02:00 - 03:00                                 10091                         -
3  03:00 - 04:00                                 10221                         -
```

I am trying to do two things:

1. Merge the multiple column headers into a single column header.
2. Drop any column that has "Unnamed:" in its column header after merging.

Here is the code I am using to do this:

```
def clean_df_colnames(df):
    # step one - merge headers
    new_columns = df.columns.values
    for index, colnames in enumerate(new_columns):
        if isinstance(colnames, str):
            continue
        names_seen = set()
        names = []
        for name in colnames:
            if name in names_seen:
                continue
            names_seen.add(name)
            names.append(name)
        name = ' '.join(names)
        new_columns[index] = name
    df.columns = new_columns
    # step two - drop extras
    cols = [c for c in df.columns if 'Unnamed:' not in c]
    df = df[cols]
    return df
```

The problem I am facing is that `df = df[cols]` is returning an error `KeyError: '[] not in index'"`. I looked it up and it seems like one cause is that I didn't set the axis when reading, so I tried by changing it to `dfs = pd.read_html(table_html, index_col=0)` instead. While this runs without error, the first column header "Time" is missing from the output.

```
              ABC|XX3 Day-ahead Total Load Forecast [A.L.1] [MW] ABC|XX3 Actual Total Load [A.L.1] [MW]
00:00 - 01:00                                              10169                         -
01:00 - 02:00                                              10092                         -
02:00 - 03:00                                              10091                         -
03:00 - 04:00                                              10221                         -
```

Is there a better way for me to merge these headers while also being able to drop the indicated columns?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My drop code was wrong. I changed to to this and it now works:

```py
df.drop(columns=[c for c in df.columns.values if 'Unnamed:' in c], inplace=True)
```